# Why is 0 size returned for every folder item, by the one drive API to get children item, for business account?

Tags: office365, onedrive, office365api

While using one drive API to get children item for a folder item, it returns sizes of all folder items as zero.But, in case of one drive personal it returns correct sizes.So, is this a glitch and will be corrected in future or is this done knowingly and will always return size of a folder as 0, regardless of their actual size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently a known gap between OneDrive for Business and Consumer. We plan to return the correct size in the future, but there are no near term plans for this yet.

Comment: Are you one One drive API user or One Drive API developer in Microsoft?

Comment: Ketaki is one of the PM's on the OneDrive API team, like me.